# Django save method called twice?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override a save method so that on creation of one model, an instance of the second model is created. However, it looks like the secondary model that I'm trying to create (`Restaurant` in this example) is being created twice. Why is that?

models.py

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              
        return "%s the place" % self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Place, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if Restaurant.objects.filter(place=self).count() == 0:
            restaurant = Restaurant.objects.create(place=self)


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
```

Comment: Can you show your `view` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your save method does not have proper indentation. I assume this was an error in cut and paste. With in that method.

```
if Restaurant.objects.filter(place=self).count() == 0:
     restaurant = Restaurant.objects.create(restaurant=self)
```

This is essentially what [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) does but does atomically.

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.

You can do the same in your own code of course with an atomic block but why bother. Just do

```
Restaurent.objects.get_or_create(place=self)
```

and isn't that `place=self` instead of `restaurent=self` as in your save method?

Comment: Thanks, yes, had some indentation errors and the wrong arg. Awesome, it looks like using `get_or_create` fixes it, makes sense as it enforces atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
obj.save(commit=False)
#change fields
obj.save()
```

First you will create save 'instance', do what you have to do, and then call the right `save()` method.